# I'm Unsure How to Write a Function for Sorting (Using the Key Parameter) and Rewrite the Function Using a Lambda Expression

Tags: python-3.x, function, sorting, lambda, optional-parameters

Create a function called last_four that takes in an ID number and returns the last four digits. For example, the number 17573005 should return 3005. Then, use this function to sort the list of ids stored in the variable, ids, from lowest to highest. Save this sorted list in the variable, sorted_ids. Hint: Remember that only strings can be indexed, so conversions may be needed.

The second part of the problem is, "Sort the list ids by the last four digits of each id. Do this using lambda and not using a defined function. Save this sorted list in the variable sorted_id"

I have defined my function definition, and the input it takes in. I have created an empty list, and then I have created a for loop that iterates through the values of my input, where I append the last four digits to the empty list I created. I do this for all items in my input. The I set the list I created equal to a sorted version of itself using the sorted function, and I have the function returning the sorted list.

I then set the variable sorted_ids equal to last_four with an input parameter specified.

```
def last_four(x):
    r = []
    for i in x:
        r.append(str(i)[-4:])

    r = sorted(r)
    print(r)
    return r

ids = [17573005, 17572342, 17579000, 17570002, 17572345, 17579329]

sorted_ids = last_four(ids)
```

When I run the code above, I get an error saying, "Error: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" since the input is a list of ids. From reading up on how to solve this, I think my result is supposed to be something like, "`sorted_ids = sorted(ids, key = last_four)`". When I try using the code snippet in the previous sentence, I still get the same TypeError as I mentioned before. I'm not sure how to write it using the optional key parameter.

I also need to write the function using a Lambda expression without having defined the function last_four and get the same result, which I am not sure how to do.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I copy + pasted your code and it worked without modification in Python 3.7.3 yielding an output of: `['0002', '2342', '2345', '3005', '9000', '9329']`. What version of Python are you currently using?

Comment: @willk, I just tried in repl.it, and it works in that environment. The environment I'm doing the exercise in is in Runestone 3.3.2 - https://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/overview/overview.html. I'm not clear which version of Python it is.

I think to pass the assignment I need to use the optional key parameter - "sorted_ids = sorted(ids, key = last_four)", which I haven't figured out how to write in Runestone. I also need to rewrite using a Lambda expression, which I'm not sure how to do.

Did you have any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are after and have posted my response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this using `sorted` with a `lambda` function as the `key`, you need to specify what you want to do for each element of the list in the `lambda` function. In this case, you want to subset to the last four numbers of each id which can only be done by converting the integer id to a string.

This means the `sorted` expression with a `lambda` function for the `key` is:

```py
ids = [17573005, 17572342, 17579000, 17570002, 17572345, 17579329]
sorted(ids, key=lambda x: str(x)[-4:])

# Output
[17570002, 17572342, 17572345, 17573005, 17579000, 17579329]
```

This says sort the list by the last four digits of each id after converting the id to a string.

An equivalent way to do this using a named function is:

```py
def last_four(x):
    return str(x)[-4:]

sorted(ids, key=last_four)
```

The choice is up to you. The `lambda` expression is less  code, but the named function (`last_four`) may be easier to understand.

Comment: The way you wrote it using sorted and key = lambda makes sense to me! 

When I try using key = last_four, I run into issues. I feel like I'm making a silly mistake. Below is what I'm trying to do:

`def last_four(x):
  return x[-4:]

ids = [17573005, 17572342, 17579000, 17570002, 17572345, 17579329]

sorted_ids = sorted(ids, key = last_four)`

Comment: You need to convert `x` to a `str` in `last_four` if you are going to do it that way.

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how to solve the problem using a named function for the `key` in `sorted`.

Comment: That did it! Silly mistakes on my part, thanks for the clear code and patience!

Comment: No problem, everyone makes silly mistakes no matter how much experience they have!

Comment: Also, if this does solve your problem (I'm happy to help if you need more), then you can checkmark the answer to let others know it has been solved.

Comment: just checkmarked your answer, thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is by taking mod of the number. Eg: 17573005%10000=3005 which is the required result.

```
def last_four(x):
    return x%10000
```

And then call this function as a key to `sorted()` function

```
ids = [17573005, 17572342, 17579000, 17570002, 17572345, 17579329]
sorted_ids = sorted(ids,key=last_four)
```

Now using lambda it would look like:

```
sorted_id = sorted(ids,key = lambda k: k%10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is wrong

def last_four(x):
    r = []
    for i in x:
        r.append(str(i)[-4:])

```
r = sorted(r)
print(r)
return r
```

ids = [17573005, 17572342, 17579000, 17570002, 17572345, 17579329]

sorted_ids = last_four(ids)

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
def last_four(x):
    x = x-17570000
    return x
a
ids = [17573005, 17572342, 17579000, 17570002, 17572345, 17579329]    
sorted_ids = sorted(ids, key=lambda x:last_four(x))
print(sorted_ids)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Ishant Nand. Please try to format your code correctly so others can easily read it.